# How do I prevent GoogleBot from finding acquisition URLs?

Tags: zope, googlebot

I have apache in front of zope 2 (multiple virtual hosts) using the standard simple rewrite rule.

I am having big issues with some of the old sites I host and googlebot.

Say I have:

- site.example.com/documents/
- site.example.com/images/i.jpg
- site.example.com/xml/
- site.example.com/flash_banner.swf

How do I stop the following from happening?

- site.example.com/documents/images/xml/i.jpg
- site.example.com/images/xml/i.jpg
- site.example.com/images/i.jpg/xml/documents/flash_banner.swf

All respond with the correct object from the last folder on the end of the URI, the old sites where not written very well and it some cases Google is going in and out of hundreds of permutations of folder structures that don’t exist but always finding large flash files. So instead of Googlebot hitting the flash file once, it's dragging it off the site thousands of times. I am in the process of moving the old sites the Django. But I need to put a halt to it in Zope. In tthe past have tried ipchains and mod_security but they are not an option this time around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find out what page is providing Google all the variant paths to the same objects. Then fix that page so that it only provides the canonical paths using the absoute_url(), absoute_url_path(), or virtual_url_path() methods of traversable objects.

You could also use [sitemaps.xml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) or [robots.txt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots.txt) to tell Google not to spider the wrong paths but that's definitely a workaround and not a fix as the above would be.

Comment: I would do what Ross suggests, since it solved my problems once. Zope2 acquisition is annoying and you can't really stop it for all Zope objects. Unless you hack `__bobo_traverse__` - which I don't recommend.

Comment: Cheers, now to find those pages/links.